# Is it safe to create many list? Will garbage collector collect them instantly?

Tags: java

I'm working on a PC Game emulator written in java. There is around 2.500.000 lines of code and lately i contribute my own code. Sometimes i'm forced to write code that it generate list on every character hit. Imagine 1.500 players hit at the same and do 10 hit per second. This mean 15.000 list generated every minute.

Is this safe? Will garbage collector collect those after code read data of them?

Comment: "it depends". It depends on so many things: what's the size of the lists, how long are they used, what hardware is this running on? What are you latency/performance goals? Generally speaking it *could* be fine and the only way to check is to **test your specific code on your specific hardware against your specific requirements**. And as an aside: if you don't have anywhere near 1500 concurrent users on a single server right now, then start making something functional first and worry about performance later.

Comment: Hello sir, max 3-4 objects inside (class type), windows 7 i7 4770 12 gb ram, they are used only for read from a method (a simple for) so some nanosecond.